# Starcraft 2 limitations on expansions

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I'm currently playing SC2 with it's free starter edition. I already loved it and planing buy it. But i've some questions.

1. If I buy only WoL, can i play ranked/unranked matches?
2. If I buy only WoL, can i reach highest level on each races? (currently stucked on 10lvl)
3. If I buy only WoL, can i receive achievements, unlocks, skins, animations?
4. If I buy only WoL, can I produce units added on HotS? (like Viper from Zerg)
5. If I buy both WoL and HotS, when new protoss expansion release, Blizzard give me free upgrade? or I should buy that too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes you can, but you can only play vs. players who are also playing Wings of Liberty. People who own HotS can set their game mode to WoL, and then you'll be able to play with them; but most players nowadays are playing HotS.
2. No, this is only limited to HotS. You can however form a party with someone who has Hots and play any game type with them. In this situation, you can gain XP (See [Spawning](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/buy-now/spawning))
3. I'm not sure in this one; You can definately earn the achivements and although the "Swarm Levels" are appereant in WoL but that feature only available in HotS, I guess you cannot unlock the skins/animations (except the decals/portraits, which you get as a reward after certain achievements).
4. No, you can only produce the units available in WoL
5. If you want to play Legacy of the Void (the second expansion for SC2), you'll have to buy it
6. Look around in retail or directly at the blizzard store, they sometimes have -50% off both the games. (I'd rather not trust some random key sellers)

   Additional info: 
   There is a [spawning-feature](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/buy-now/spawning) in SC2. Basically, you can play WoL/HotS with your starter edition if you play with friends that own WoL/HotS (You can find more info on spawning at the linked site)

Comment: Basically, I decided buy it, because of more unlocks, levels, achievements, and most importantly ranked matches. Thanks for answer. But now few doubt left.
4. If I can't produce HotS units, isn't it worse than Starter edition?
1. These days how much guys playing WoL ranked matches? They all playing HotS or still many playing WoL?
6. Can you give me some trusted links :) ?

Comment: @GereltOd To question 4: Remember that with the starter editition (as far as I know) you **cannot** play the full campaign nor ranked games (and also games vs. AI are limited to 4 maps I think). To 1: Most of the people are playing HotS, but I think there is still a good amount of WoL-players (see [sc2ranks](http://www.sc2ranks.com/wol/global/1v1/all/all) for more stats. 6. Not really since I bought it directly from the blizzard store.

Comment: Weird. When I go to Purchase menu, it says WoL is 499.00 RUB. Around 14$. But on Amazon, its 33.94$. Why so much difference? And I'm not even from Russian, I prefer pay USD, so I just created ticket (guess they wont answer fast). You think, If I change my payment currency to USD, it will become 33$ ?

Comment: ... I am not sure, but I think that you can play with anyone - when you have HoS you can choose if you want to play "HoS or WoL mood", or something like that. It is actually the same system than in SC1, when playing with expansion you play with the mood you desire.

Comment: @GereltOd because amazon can set its own upmarket value on it, and they send a physical copy (a DVD) rather than the digital only token on steam

Comment: @GereltOd - Just purchase it from Blizzard.  You are guaranteed the best price

Comment: "digital only token on steam" Steam ?? Well, you are right anyway, on Blizzard site, you can purchase the digital copy that is cheaper. There are still some people playing WoL. You won't have any problem to find people in the ladder.